# Keycard Minecraft system

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way with command blocks (in minecraft) to scan a player for a name tag named "Keycard" and if they have it open the door and if not it does nothing?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: There are ways on YouTube where you can put a written book in a dropper and if it is the keycard then the door will open. I'm not sure about “scanning a player”.

Comment: That is what I found. I haven't tested it because I only have MCPE. https://youtube.com/watch?v=QRVJ7fZwEGA

Answer (score 1):

you could create a scoreboard objective that checks if a person has the key card and the command would go like this.
First, in an impulse command block /scoreboard objectives add KeyCard dummy activate it and it will add a scoreboard objective called keycard.
Now put this command in a repeating always active command block. Put in this command in the command block
/testfor @a[score_KeyCard_min=1,r=3]

then add a comparator and repeator to look like this it will normally be off unless a player is within a 3 block radius with a score of one keycard.[image]

now add two impulse commands one command will have this command init

/scoreboard players add @p KeyCard 1
this will add 1 keycard to the nearest player

and in the next command

/scoreboard players remove @p KeyCard 1

just in case if you want to take the keycard away.

the testfor command (the one in the picture) will create a Redstone current if you have a Keycard score of 1 and are within a 3 block radius which you could hook up to an iron door.

Good luck

CreepedOutNizo,